# Raspberry Pi: Unable to reboot (unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2) - on brand new sdcard/image

Tags: pi-4, boot, raspberry-pi-os

I got some new Sandisk 32gb Ultra sdcards installed Pi OS on them etc - but when booting the Pi they gave the error in the title - all the same.

Comment: Note that Sandisk Ultras are very commonplace (I have a stack of them I've used with pis, never any problem) so the correlation you are drawing here can't be correct or we would have seen this here before.

Comment: @goldilocks I have used loads of them too... its just this last batch that are causing issues... out of the box, pi os imaged, boot in a Pi 3 and they fail.

Comment: I have ordered a new power supply... see if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

The sd's come with some software installed by the manufacturer which the Pi OS install program doesn't/can't clear properly.

So just format the SD's before you start using the official 'SD Association SD Card Formatter' software from here https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/

Once the disk is properly formatted, then go ahead and install your OS etc...

Comment: This is unlikely as the Pi OS images overwrite any formatting -- it does not matter what is on the card to start with.

Comment: @goldilocks this didn't fix it -- reformatting and reinstalling allowed it boot and finish the initial setup, but on a reboot it failed again. (I have four new cards... I have only redone two, as it is quite time consuming...)

Comment: @goldilocks this is normally true but the imager does not reformat the card so faulty blocks can remain. I have used the SD Association SD Card Formatter to resurrect failing cards (and hide the faulty blocks) although ultimately they need to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I now believe these were fake cards. They ran for a bit then failed.

I got cards from another source and it is clear (for instance) that the printing on the card is better quality (less bleed, less grainy etc), so I am returning the duds for a refund.

I would probably delete the question - but there is a good tip on the SD Association Card Formatter hiding faulty blocks which is useful to know if you are having card issues!